# No exception raised when saving an empty field with null=False - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-model-field

I have the following model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=False, unique=True)
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, unique=True)
```

And used the Django shell to save a user instance with referral_code undefined:

```
u = User(email="test@example.com")
u.save()
```

This did not raise an exception. My understanding was that null=False would require referral_code to be set - Is this not the case? How would I achieve that behaviour?

**update**

I notice that the field is set to `u.referral_code=''`, so given the uniqueness constraint, this has raised an exception when I tried to repeat the process with a new instance. I would rather the exception was thrown because I did not set the field...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of your `referral_code` is not `null`, it is `''` (blank string). This is the default of `CharField`.

---

*Updated along with question:*

You can raise an error before the data is stored in the database by overriding `save` on the model

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=False, unique=True)
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        assert self.email, "The 'email' field must be populated."
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It should be noted that this is not to be preferred over form validation where possible.

---

*Update now that newer features of Django are available:*

[Django's Constraints](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/) allow you to add custom database constraints:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=False, unique=True)
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=(~models.Q(referral_code='')),
                name='referral_code_populated',
            )
        ]
```